# Solving for beta with gamma function

Tags: problem-solving, gamma-function

I am trying to solve this and Wolfram is giving me an answer of $b=18$ but I keep getting it down to a quadratic where I have to solve using the $-b$ formula and not getting the answer.

$$2b(b+1)\frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(b+3)} = 0.1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$\Gamma(b+3) = (b+2)\Gamma(b+2) = (b + 2)(b + 1)\Gamma(b + 1) = (b + 2)(b + 1)b\Gamma(b),$$
so your equation becomes 
$$2b(b+1)\frac{1}{(b+2)(b + 1)b} = 0.1,$$
or
$$\frac{2}{b + 2} = \frac{1}{10}.$$
This yields the linear equation
$$b + 2 = 20,$$
so the solution is $b = 18$.